# androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelStoreOwner in ViewModelProvider cannot be applied to androidx.lifecycle.LifeCycleOwner

Tags: android, mvvm, viewmodel, classcastexception, android-viewmodel

I am trying to implement ViewModel, LiveData within a Fragment. After going through the [Medium Blog](https://medium.com/@BladeCoder/architecture-components-pitfalls-part-1-9300dd969808), I tried to use the method getViewLifecycleOwner() while declaring the ViewModel Object.

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
viewModel = new ViewModelProvider(getViewLifecycleOwner()).get(MainActivityViewModel.class);
}
```

But it shows up the following error,

> **androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelStoreOwner** in ViewModelProvider cannot be applied to **androidx.lifecycle.LifeCycleOwner**

[image]

When I try to Cast this to `ViewModelStoreOwner`, app crashes by showing the below error,

> **java.lang.ClassCastException:** androidx.fragment.app.FragmentViewLifecycleOwner cannot be cast to androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelStoreOwner

How to declare the lifecycle of the `Fragment` with the `ViewModel` efficiently?

Comment: The problem the blog post describes is with using the wrong `LifecycleOwner` when you `observe`, not with getting a ViewModel.

Answer (score 1):

Use this to scope your viewmodel to your fragment:

```
viewModel = new ViewModelProvider(this).get(MainActivityViewModel.class);
```

Or this if you want it scoped to your activity:

```
viewModel = new ViewModelProvider(requireActivity()).get(MainActivityViewModel.class);
```

Comment: I have to set the scope of the viewmodel to my fragment and I have done the same as you mentioned in onViewCreated(), also tried with onCreateView(), the viewmodel is getting reinitializes again and again which leads to set the observer multiple times.. 

How to resolves this?

Answer (score 0):

Fragment is a subclass of `LifecycleOwner`. So you can directly pass `Fragment` reference to the `LifecycleOwner` parameter.

Code will be like this.

```java
viewModel = new ViewModelProvider(this).get(MainActivityViewModel.class);
```

Comment: I have done the same as you mentioned in onViewCreated(), also tried with onCreateView(), the ViewModel is getting reinitializes again and again which leads to set the observer multiple times.

Comment: Also, you can check whether ViewModel is initialised already or not. If it's null, only then assign new ViewModel to it.